# How to organize the names of objects in the outliner?

Tags: outliner

The objects in the blender cannot have the same name. So you can’t get namespace effect through collection or parenting.

For example,
There are three character heads with different facial expressions, and they have facial elements under them such as eyes, nose and mouth. This is the same organization as the image below.
[image]

However, the objects in the blender must all have different names, so for me the organization like the image below is best.
But I think this naming method is too complicated.
[image]

Is there a better name management?
How do you name the objects?

Comment: Personally, I just let Blender run wild with the .001, .002 extensions. So long as my objects are organized within collections, I don't mind it too much. The name just needs to tell me what component it is, and the collection tells me what context (larger object) it belongs to.